# how to include subject line to perl email script?

Tags: perl

I am fairly new to perl, how can i get the subject line to show on the email in my code below? Right now it only sends the email with out the subject line.

The recipient receives an email depending on the zip code that matches their email account as shown in the code below.

Also when it sends an email with the data, the email @ sign doesnt show properly. How can I fix this?

Thanks

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
%form=&parse_form();
$other_email=&lookup($form{'zipcode'});
$subject = 'Test Email';
$body=
"Customer Name: $form{'name'}\n".
"Customer Phone: $form{'phone'}\n".
"Customer Email: $form{'email'}\n".
"Customer Zip: $form{'zipcode'}\n";

mailsend('myemail@gmail.com',$body) and print "<b>Thank You!</b><br>\n";
mailsend($form{'email'},$body) and print "<b>Your email has been sent.</b><br>\n";
mailsend($other_email,$body) and print "<b>Please hit back to exit this page.</b><br>\n";

#helper functions
sub lookup {
    $contents=`cat postcodes.txt`;
    ($result)=$contents=~m/\b$_[0]=(.*)\b/;
    print "<b>Corresponding email address  for zip $_[0] was [$result]</b><br>\n";
    return $result;
}

sub mailsubject {
$subject = 'Test Email';
}

sub mailsend {
    open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
    print MAIL "To: $_[0]\n\n";
    print MAIL "See email below!\n\n";
    print MAIL "$_[1]\n";
    print MAIL "Thank you\n";
    close(MAIL);
    return true;
}

sub parse_form {
    ($hash{'name'}) = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}=~/name=(.*?)&/;
    ($hash{'phone'}) = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}=~/phone=(.*?)&/;
    ($hash{'email'}) = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}=~/email=(.*?)&/;
    ($hash{'zipcode'}) = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}=~/zipcode=(.*?)&/;
    return %hash;
}
```

Comment: your edit deleted your earlier question and asked a completely different one, making all of the earlier answers to your question meaningless. If you want to ask a follow-up or a new question, then please create a new question at this site.

Comment: The @ sign shows as "%40" in the email. any idea how to fix that?

Comment: If you used the parameter parsing features in CGI.pm then the `%40` conversion would be handled for you.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add an additional header for the Subject:

```
sub mailsend {
    my ($recip, $subject, $body) = @_;  # <- extract into variables

    open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
    print MAIL "To: $recip\n";
    print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n";   # <- added Subject line
    print MAIL "\n";                    # end of headers
    print MAIL "See email below!\n\n";
    print MAIL "$body\n";
    print MAIL "Thank you\n";
    close(MAIL);

    return true;
}
```

This seems like a lot of extra work since there is already a Perl module on CPAN that processes email in a much simpler fashion: [`MIME:Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/MIME-Lite-3.030/lib/MIME/Lite.pm)

Comment: All headers need to go before `\n\n`

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't put a subject line in the email.. it just adds it into the email with the body?

Comment: As @mob mentioned all headers need to come before `\n\n`, I missed that.

Comment: I tried to do that and now it doesnt even send an email... can you please explain what you mean @mob?

Comment: `sendmail` expects one or more headers, followed by a newline, followed by the body of the message. Each header has the format "*field*: *value*" and ends with a single newline.

Comment: I think i get what your saying, thanks. If you have time, can you show that in the actual code? Because even though I have a subject line working now, its printing the body twice.

Comment: Re: MIME::Lite - from its pod: "WAIT! MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else."

Comment: @Oesor They don't appear to be taking the suggestion anyway, so it doesnt matter. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks a lot mob and Hunter McMillen. I wish people didnt post random useless comments if they dont have anything constructive to say that relates to the question. @simbabque

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use external modules, using Email::Simple and Email::Sender would allow you to not need to reimplement the wheel:

```
use strict;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Simple;
use Email::Simple::Creator;

sub mailsend {
    my ($to, $subject, $body) = @_;
    my $email = Email::Simple->create(
        header => [
            To      => $to,
            From    => '"My Script" <myscript@example.com>',
            Subject => $subject,
        ],
        body => $body,
      );
    sendmail($email);
}
```

Comment: I didnt want to use those but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Why didn't you want to use those? What's the point of using Perl if you ignore most of its power (i.e. CPAN)?